# Best database for faceted search over 300M rows

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, elasticsearch, rdbms

I have a dataset with **300 Million** products and I want to perform faceted searches over that dataset. Each row is about **35kb wide**.

Most of the queries I want to perform are something like:

*Select all products in these 2 subcategories, that were created between these dates, that have a price bigger than x, that are sold by this retailer, that have these words in the description.*

The results of these queries will usually be tens of thousands of rows.

I'm trying to figure out what the right database solution should be. My initial thought was to just do it with PostgreSQL but it has proven to be too slow (queries taking more than 30s). I've made sure I have the right indexes but it is still slow. I am going to try and add more RAM and CPU power to see how much of a difference that makes.

The next thing I was going to try is Elastic Search. 
Do you have any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: 35KB is a lot of data per row. Are you sure you're using the right schema?

Comment: Yes. Some of the product descriptions can be pretty large.

Comment: Usually the better results come from tweaking the schema and the queries. You showed none.

Comment: You could always move heavy metadata to another table you can `JOIN` in if and only if it's necessary.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto The schema would be similar to the schema of an amazon product. There is a products table, each row has a number of attributes about that product (description, name, price, etc). There is also a stores table, where each store has many products. Hoping that's enough for you to get a sense of the dataset. Thanks for your time and help anyway.